# How to set bounds of actionSheet imageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiactionsheet, cgrectmake

I need to change the bounds of imageView property on ActionSheet,

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

        #pragma UIActionSheetDelegate Methods
        - (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
           /*[[[actionSheet valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] imageView].frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25.0f, 25.0f);*/

           [[[actionSheet valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] imageView].bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25.0f, 25.0f);

           /*UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25.0f, 25.0f)];
           imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"symbol-pin.png"];
           [[actionSheet superview] addSubview:imgView];*/ 
    }
```

Nothing is happen after coding:

```
[[[actionSheet valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] imageView].bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25.0f, 25.0f);
```

Here the code for creating ActionSheet

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

    - (IBAction)showModeOptions:(id)sender {
       if (!modeOptions) {
         modeOptions = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Pin",@"Linie", @"Polygon", nil];

          [[[modeOptions valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"symbol-pin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

          [[[modeOptions valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"symbol-line.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

          [[[modeOptions valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:2] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"symbol-polygon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

          modeOptions.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
      }
      [modeOptions showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar]; 
}
```

The images are 88 x 88px and the result after the previos code is:

```
http://i46.tinypic.com/v4ck20.png
```

And I need the images in 25 x 25 px like the bounds of the imageView I set. 
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this following code ..

```
-(void)actionSheetClicked
{

if(!self.modeOptions)
    {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dummy",nil]; //Here I add dummy button for getting cancel button style.
        self.modeOptions = actionSheet;
        [actionSheet release];
    }
    self.modeOptions.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;


    [self.modeOptions showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];//Here i show from tab bar, you can showfromview also
//    [self.modeOptions setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)//frame size for action sheet in both modes
    {
        [self.modeOptions setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];

    }
    else
    {
        [self.modeOptions setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480,250)];
    }
    UIButton *buttonDum = (UIButton *)[[self.modeOptions subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

    [buttonDum setHidden:YES];//hide dummy button..

    UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton *)[[self.modeOptions subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

    if( !self.button1)
    {

        UIButton *Btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 40, 70, 70)];//**Here I use 70 X 70 px image , you can edit it**
        self.button1 = Btn;
        [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(invokeFirstBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn1Image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.modeOptions addSubview:self.button1];
        [Btn release];
    }
    if( !self.button2)
    {
        UIButton *Btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 40, 70, 70)];//**Here I use 70 X 70 px image , you can edit it**
        self.button2 = sharBtn;
        [self.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(invokeButton2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn2Image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.modeOptions addSubview:self.button2];
        [Btn release];
    }
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)//frame size for action sheet in both modes
    {
        cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 140, 220, 40);
        self.button1.frame = CGRectMake(65, 40, 70, 70);
        self.button2.frame = CGRectMake(175, 40, 70, 70);
    }
    else
    {
        cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(135, 140, 220, 40);
        self.button1.frame = CGRectMake(155, 40, 70, 70);
        self.button2.frame = CGRectMake(260, 40, 70, 70);
    }
}
```

This is working code.. Check with this. You can change with frame size as your wish... You can create actionsheet without dummy button...